# Why PHP's md5 is different from OpenSSL's md5?

Tags: php, openssl, md5

I am quite confused as to why I am seeing different results for md5 hashing in PHP and in OpenSSL.

Here is the code that I am running:

```
php -r "echo md5('abc');"
```

Results in: 900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72

While this:

```
echo abc | openssl md5
```

Results in: 0bee89b07a248e27c83fc3d5951213c1

Why?

Comment: FWIW, you're in good company making this mistake. This question has been asked several times on Stack Overflow, for example: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147875/difference-in-sha512-between-python-hashlib-and-sha512sum-tool
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604892/is-the-md5sum-linux-command-working-right
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843383/why-does-perl-and-bin-sha1-give-different-results
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799815/why-is-the-same-input-returning-two-different-md5-hashes

Comment: well that makes me feel a bit better :) thnx :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is only one way to compute MD5.

A blind guess is that the second one also includes a newline inside the string being hashed.

Yeh, verified it. That's it.

Comment: That is weird, but `echo` returns a newline. Use `echo -n abc | openssl md5` to get the same output as the PHP version.

Answer (score 8):

As everyone noted, the problem is that echo prints an extra newline.

However, the solution proposed (`echo -n`) is not completely correct. According to the POSIX standard, "[Implementations shall not support any options.](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html)" You'll make the world a bit better if you don't use it.
Use

```
printf %s abc | openssl md5
```

or simply

```
printf abc | openssl md5
```

Comment: The POSIX standard also says *If the first operand is `-n`, or if any of the operands contain a backslash ( `'\'` ) character, the results are implementation-defined.* (further down the same page) - it's the XSI extensions that say that -n must be handled as a normal string (and if the system is XSI-conforming, then you can use `echo "abc\c"` instead)

Answer (score 6):

`echo` normally adds a new line character at the end of the string it outputs; that is the reason the MD5 values are different.

Try with `echo -n abc | openssl md5`.

Answer (score 1):

As jdehaan notes, if you tell echo not output a newline, you get the answer you expect

```
echo -n "abc" | openssl md5
900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72
```