# openssl md5 in command line and php md5 produce different results

Tags: php, openssl, md5

Here is the string I am submitting as text file (csr.txt) with command line
https://pastebin.com/qBLJcKQB

openssl command I am passing is:

> openssl req -noout -modulus -in csr.txt | openssl md5
>
> e199562f2e9f6a29826745d09faec3a6

Here is the php script version for getting the md5 hash

```
<?php 

$csr = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----';

$csrDetails = openssl_pkey_get_details(openssl_csr_get_public_key($csr)); 

echo md5($csrDetails['rsa']['n']);
?>
```

php script produces:

> 718926bb97aabc0fd1116fa25c295612

I have seen other threads which talk about excluding new line but in my case I am not using echo but rather using openssl. [Why PHP's md5 is different from OpenSSL's md5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169605/why-phps-md5-is-different-from-openssls-md5)

Appreciate some assistance.

**NOTE:** If I drop from the command line "| openssl md5" & in the php script remove md5() then the results are identical

[image]

php script produces:

```
echo strtoupper(bin2hex($csrDetails['rsa']['n']));

B1FCD68F28FBCE554595709A18C1FA1A3DE3B16576B42EAB2E744A2B8C7B854688D09AE2A975104CD60A4E05610EC951D4AD33AC961C6AAA66C1BE0FAD427FD91639B22ED0BC79E777027734E74714E2BC8209F542A46F145A38B2C3E9616198EB701B8F40DFF4EEA28041D0450B67E7FF5692433C7AF2CB992D9961FF6FE96F
```

Comment: *"but in my case I am not using echo but rather using openssl."* - It doesn't matter. If that text file contains an empty line at the end of it, it does contain an (invisible) newline `\n`. You can try trimming it or get rid of the empty line.

Comment: i added this bit of code to trim new lines in the php script but it made no difference to the result: $csr = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $csr);

Comment: Try `str_replace("\r\n", "", $csr)` or `str_replace("\n", "", $csr)` - what you're doing now is looking for `\r\n` and replacing it with `\n`. Also run a var_dump

Comment: doing this breaks the php script as the new lines are required for php's built in openssl library to read the string.

Comment: Well, I upvoted your question. Let's see if someone else can find something. I'm quite baffled. I hope this gets resolved, *cheers*

Comment: Well, I don't know php, but my guess is that "$csrDetails['rsa']['n']" is producing the modulus in a raw binary form. The openssl command line is printing out a hex string representation of the modulus (which includes the string prefix "Modulus=").

Comment: @Matt Caswell, correct. with php we can convert from binary to hex using the built in function bin2hex() - if you look at my example the modulus matches. The issue is with getting the md5 digest hash, that's where it's different.

Comment: My point is that in the php version you're hashing the binary representation of the modulus, i.e. the binary data 0xB1FCD68F28.... With the command line version you are hashing a printable text string representation of the modulus, i.e. the string "Modulus=B1FCD68F28...". Assuming you are on a machine using an ASCII based character set, this translates to the binary data 0x4D6F64756C... Therefore you are hashing different data in each case and so you are going to get a different result. As an aside I ought to point out that md5 was broken a long time ago and is considered completely insecure.

Comment: @MattCaswell you make a good observation. Following your logic, if I retrieve the MD5 hash of the string e.g. md5('Modulus=B1FCD68F28...') shouldn't we then expect the same result as the command line? unfortunately not - I get "eaec7531a37aae6a9fb945b79160d6bd" whereas command line is "e199562f2e9f6a29826745d09faec3a6"

Comment: Looks like openssl is adding a "\n" to the end of the output from the "openssl req ..." command. From php try running md5("Modulus=B1FCD68F28...\n"), i.e. note using " instead of ' and the \n on the end. I tried that and got "e199562f2e9f6a29826745d09faec3a6" - the same as the OpenSSL command line

Comment: @MattCaswell, that was it. Thanks for your assistance! Can you post your latest comment as a solution to get the credit?

Comment: Solution added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the php version you are hashing the binary representation of the modulus, i.e. the binary data 0xB1FCD68F28.... With the command line version you are hashing a printable text string representation of the modulus, i.e. the string "Modulus=B1FCD68F28...". Assuming you are on a machine using an ASCII based character set, this translates to the binary data 0x4D6F64756C... Therefore you are hashing different data in each case and so you are going to get a different result.

Also it looks like openssl is adding a "\n" to the end of the output from the "openssl req ..." command. From php try running md5("Modulus=B1FCD68F28...\n"), i.e. note using " instead of ' and the \n on the end. I tried that and got "e199562f2e9f6a29826745d09faec3a6" - the same as the OpenSSL command line

Comment: To make php match the command line version I ended up doing this:

`echo "Modulus=".strtoupper(bin2hex($csrDetails['rsa']['n']))."\n";`